# How rewrite a url slug to a parameter using .htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url

I'm looking for the regex url rewriting entries for .htaccess - specifically, I'd like a way to re-write:

```
/site/this-is-my-slug/
```

to

```
/site/?slug=this-is-my-slug
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ site/?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `QSA` flag will copy over any query string from your original URL request so remove it if you don't want this functionality.